# RMarkdown change the order of author and title

Tags: r-markdown, text-alignment, author

I'm trying to align right author and put it before the title that is centered.

```
---
author: "Author name" 
title: "Title name"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{titling}
    - \preauthor{\begin{flushright}}
    - \postauthor{\end{flushright}}

---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `}` lacking at the end of `- \preauthor{\begin{flushright}`. In order to move the author up, you may use `\vspace*{-1.5cm}`.

Code:

```
---
author: "Author name" 
title: "Title name"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{titling}
    - \preauthor{\begin{flushright}\vspace*{-1.5cm}}
    - \postauthor{\end{flushright}}
---
```

-output
[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks, but author is still after Title. I want it before the title.